# SSL validation failure - knife ec2 with chef 12

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

Trying to create an aws server using 'knife ec2' and bootstrap-version 12 but failing on SSL validation.

'SSL Validation failure connecting to host'

It seems a solution would be to run 'knife ssl fetch' to get the server ssl certificate but I cant work out exactly how or when to run this

(All other setup seems ok, EC2 instance is created, ssh works, chef 12 downloaded, error is on creation of new client identity using validator key)

```
10.x.x.x Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
10.x.x.x Creating a new client identity for test_create using the validator key.
10.x.x.x [2015-01-21T18:22:48+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: chef.xxxx - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
10.x.x.x 
10.x.x.x ================================================================================
10.x.x.x Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "test_create"
10.x.x.x ================================================================================
10.x.x.x
```

Comment: Please include the error. Is it failing on talking to the Chef server or to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Just run 'knife ssl fetch'....

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you use `knife ssl` to fix this. Please see https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/10/31/ssl-certificate-validation-in-chef/ for a more detailed walkthrough of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your response but not sure how it relates to getting 'knife ec2 create' to run 'knife ssl fetch'  on the newly created instance which seems to be what is required. Or have I missed something?

Comment: With newer versions of Chef, `knife boostrap` (which `ec2 server create` uses internally too) automatically copies over your local `trusted_certs` folder. That will ensure your new server can verify the Chef Server certificate.

Comment: So are you saying I need to upgrade my chef version? At the moment this is not working as you suggest